# Azure Django Web App: raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

Tags: django, azure-web-app-service, settings, secret-key

I'm trying to deploy my django app on azure from the repo on GitHub. In the settings.py file, I dont want to store the secret key directly on GitHub, so I added that on the configuration application setting of the Azure app page. To retrieve it, my settings.py file has

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

The error I'm getting is:
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

Am I properly retrieving the secret key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the environment variable correctly.

Firstly, you could **set** the environment variable in `settings.py` like below, rather than **retrieve** it in this file.

```
SECRET_KEY = '12345'
```

You could retrieve the variable in your code like what you displayed:

```
secret_key = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

Considering you don't want to expose your `SECRET_KEY` value on GitHub, you could set a temp value for invoking, which is required. After deploy, the value on portal App Settings would cover the value.

Comment: I set the actual secret key on the portal. To set a temp value, would that be SECRET_KEY='...'       SECRET_KEY=os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

Answer (score 1):

1. pip install python-dotenv
2. Create a .env file in project root and add to .gitignore file.
3. In the .env file add the following variable or something similar
   SECRET_KEY='12345'
4. Go to SETTINGS.py in the project folder and import load_dotenv

from dotenv import load_dotenv

5. Call load_dotenv to load variables

load_dotenv()

secret_key = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

6. Then use the variable wherever you please

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).